# How to find a string on fileA, select some text from that string and replace a string on fileB?

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

I have a fileA and a fileB. In **fileA**, I want my script to find for a specific stringA; then, with `sed` command paste only a part of stringA on a **file B** (replacing with part of a specific stringB in **fileB**).

Eg.

```
fileA
ashdjkahsjd
asjkdhajsdh
Recommended Weight: 0.546 (this is the string of interest)
```

```
fileB
asdajskdha
kjashdjahsd
WGHT      0.495 (this is the part of FILE B I need to replace)
```

I want to select only the text of stringA (0.546) and replace 0.495 on fileB with 0.546, so, new fileB will be:

```
NEW fileB
asdajskdha
kjashdjahsd
WGHT      0.546
```

Using only `sed` doesn't work for me because it replaces a stringA with a stringB in the same file, but my stringsA and B are from different files. Also, they are generated "randomly" (via a program).

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format the contents of your file as code. This is very hard to read.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually do it with `sed` (and another tool to match the first file). For instance:

```
$ sed -E "s/(WGHT\s*).*/\1$(grep -oP 'Recommended Weight: \K[0-9.]+' fileA)/" fileB 
asdajskdha
kjashdjahsd
WGHT 0.546
```

Or just save it in a variable first:

```
$ wght=$(sed -En 's/Recommended Weight: *([0-9.]+)/\1/p' fileA)
$ sed -E "s/(WGHT\s*).*/\1$wght/" fileB
asdajskdha
kjashdjahsd
WGHT 0.546
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR==NR && $2 == "Weight:"{ weights[spotted++]=$3} FNR!=NR && $1 != "WGHT" { print } FNR!=NR && $1=="WGHT" { print "WGHT", weights[replaced++]} ' in1 in2 > out2
```

This will create a new file, `out2`, that has your desired output data.  It can then be moved wherever you like.

```
$ cat out2
asdajskdha
kjashdjahsd
WGHT 0.546
```

Answer (score 3):

This script create `new_file_b.txt`.

**Usage:** `./script.sh file_a.txt file_b.txt > new_file_b.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
/Recommended Weight: /{
    value=$3;
}
NR != FNR {
    if($1 == "WGHT") {
        print $1 OFS value; 
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
' "$1" "$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed` you can do it as follows:

```
sed -Ez '
   N;s/.*\nRecommended Weight: (\S+)\n.*\x00(.*\nWGHT[[:blank:]]+)\S+\n/\2\1\n/
' fileA fileB
```

Where the `-E` option turns on the `extended regex facility` and `-z` option treats each file as a single string and multiple files are null(`\0`) separated.